# Recommended CPU/RAM VPS settings to query 50,000 entries

Tags: server

I'm running a very simple query on a text field...

```
{% set query = craft.request.getQuery('email') %}
```

Locally, with one entry on my machine, I'm getting a response time of 332ms. We were assuming around 3,000 total entries, but 3 days in, I'm at 15,000 and climbing by hundreds per hour.

What would be a good starting point for CPU/RAM on a VPS if I assume that we could hit 50,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU won't be the issue more the RAM if you expect to pull in all those results. But it's not much anyways.... A 1 CPU/1GB RAM on Digitalocean will be enough.

Comment: You could always throw PHP 7 on there which is [crazy better](http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/php-7) at memory management, too! :)

Comment: Setting up a digital ocean droplet and PHP 7 through Server Pilot. I'll report back once it's up.

Comment: How often does the data need to be "updated"?  Not sure what your app is doing but if you can afford to do any sort of caching, that'll reduce server load immensely.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't cache. I'm using craft as a sweepstakes entry system and I have to check to make sure there aren't duplicate entries with a json validation system. Works pretty slick.

Comment: @BradBell switching to PHP 7 gave me killer increases... Went from a 2.3s query to a 330ms query on 17,000 entries and only using around 500mb of RAM to do it.

Comment: @brunam crazy, right?

Comment: Wow! That's not a small performance decrease.